Looking to condense python code for a math game (Very new to python)
import random

correct_g = 0
incorrect_g = 0

while True:
    user_input = input('Would you like to add, sub, multi? type "end" to end the game : ').lower()

    if user_input == 'add':
        number1: int = random.randrange(1, 100)
        number2: int = random.randrange(1, 100)
        add_answer = number1 + number2
        print(number1, ' + ', number2)
        add_question = input('What is the sum of these two numbers? ')
        if int(add_question) == add_answer:
            print('That is correct!')
            correct_g += 1
            pass

        else:
            print('Incorrect. whomp whomp:(')
            incorrect_g += 1
            pass

    elif user_input == 'sub':
        number3: int = random.randrange(1, 100)
        number4: int = random.randrange(1, 100)
        sub_answer = number3 - number4
        print(number3, ' - ', number4)
        sub_question = input('What is the sum of these two numbers? ')
        if int(sub_question) == sub_answer:
            print('That is correct!')
            correct_g += 1
            pass

        else:
            print('Incorrect. whomp whomp:(')
            incorrect_g += 1
            pass


    elif user_input == 'multi':
        number5: int = random.randrange(1, 100)
        number6: int = random.randrange(1, 100)
        multi_answer = number5 * number6
        print(number5, ' * ', number6)
        multi_question = input('What is the sum of these two numbers? ')
        if int(multi_question) == multi_answer:
            print('That is correct!')
            correct_g += 1
            pass

        else:
            print('Incorrect. whomp whomp:(')
            incorrect_g += 1
            pass

    elif user_input == 'end':
        print('You got ', correct_g, ' questions right!')
        print('You got ', incorrect_g, ' questions wrong.')
        print('Thank you for playing!')
        break

    else:
        print('I do not understand.')
        pass

I'm looking for ways to condense some the if, elif, and number generators. I feel like copy/paste and changing a few words if very inefficient way of creating branches off the first user_input. I'm not to sure how else to do it, and I'm willing to start from scratch if someone recommends a lesson for me to look up and learn from.

Read it:  https://builtin.com/software-engineering-perspectives/python-calculator  Should give you some ideas.

You can use a dictionary like {'add': ('+', lambda x, y: x + y)}

This question might fade better at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Nice work so far, Jacob. The next thing to do is to get familiar with Python's functions and see if you can break off pieces of your program into functions - it can be kind of like getting Python to do that code copying that you were talking about for you!
You could put each of the branches into its own function, or you could look for common functionality and move that into their own function. For example, to create a pair of random numbers you could write:
def random_pair(max=100) -> (int, int):
  return (random.randint(1, max), random.randint(1, max))

You probably want to use randint() for your game, so you get integers. Good luck, and keep it up!

You are creating two random numbers between 1,100 regardless of choice. Why not just create them before the choices and always use number1 and number2? You are right copy and pasting code is often a bad sign.
You can create a function that is more flexible and takes the choice as input to create the branches.
import random

def branch(sign):
    if sign=="end":
        return -1
    global correct_g, incorrect_g
    number1 = random.randrange(1, 100)
    number2 = random.randrange(1, 100)
    
    def sub(a, b):
        return a - b

    def add(a, b):
        return a + b

    def multi(a, b):
        return a * b

    # Functions as dict values
    sign2func = {
        "sub": sub,
        "add": add,
        "multi": multi
    }
    
    sign2symbol = {
        "sub": "-",
        "add": "+",
        "multi": "*"
    }
    
    sign2operation = {
        "sub": "difference",
        "add": "sum",
        "multi": "product"
    }

    # Call the appropriate function from the dictionary
    sub_answer = sign2func[sign](number1, number2)

    print(f"{number1} {sign2symbol[sign]} {number2}")
    sub_question = input(f'What is the {sign2operation[sign]} of these two numbers? ')
    
    if int(sub_question) == sub_answer:
        print('That is correct!')
        correct_g += 1
    else:
        print('Incorrect. whomp whomp:(')
        incorrect_g += 1

correct_g = 0
incorrect_g = 0

while True:
    user_input = input('Would you like to add, sub, multi? Type "end" to end the game: ').lower()
    print(user_input)
    if user_input == "end":
        break
    try:
        res=branch(user_input)
        if res==-1:
            break
    except KeyError:
        print('I do not understand.')

instead of using 3 dictionaries, you could join them into one dictionary that has a list as value and then pic the right value out of the list.
